# Realm - Object has been deleted or invalidated

Tags: ios, swift, realm, persistent-storage

I've build an app that uses Realm as persistent storage and from time to time I encounter problem with accessing deleted Realm objects. My database consists of objects that are updated/deleted every 12 hours. Lets suppose the object is deleted when filtering an array of realm objects.
Here is a sample code:

```
let objects = databaseManager.getObjects()
// Here the sync is prepared and one of the array elements is removed
filteredObjects = objects.filter { ... } // Here I've got a fatal exception
```

What is a proper solution of handling such situation? Should I check if an object is invalidated while filtering?

UPDATE

To be more precise, this is the function from the databaseManager. It returns Swift objects, not Realm objects.

```
func getObjects() -> [Object] {
    return database.objects(Object.self).toArray(ofType: Object.self)
}
```

'Objects' are being updated every 12 hours. They are downloaded from the backend, new ones are stored and those outdated are deleted. I'm talking about a situation when I make some operations on the collection (map, filter etc.) and the sync mechanism starts working. 
What should I do when objects I'm working on are deleted from Realm?

Comment: A little off topic but be aware that using Swift filtering is not the same as using a Realm filter. The Realm filter will product a Results object that can be Realm Observed and worked with via Realm functions. Swift filters return a LazyFilterSequence which is not a Realm object. Generally speaking (very generally) you should filter Realm results with a Realm filter. See [Realm Filtering](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering) `realm.objects(YourObject.self).filter("property = 'some value')

Comment: To your question; I think more code is needed to understand the use case. How/why is an object being invalidated while filtering? What's causing that to happen? What's happening with the actual filter? What does this line do `let realmObjects = databaseManager.getObjects()` e.g. what are realmObjects? The code in your question works so we really need to see code that doesn't work. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay I've added a bit more description. Is it clear now? :)

Comment: It's still way too vague. We don't know what your code does or how it does it - e.g. `database.objects(Object.self)` is something you came up with. `filteredObjects = objects.filter { ... }` is some kind of filter but we don't know what the filter is filtering. Without context there's not way we can understand what that does. See the link in my above comment - we need to see a clear *minimal* and functional example, not just a few lines of code.

Comment: but it doesn't mind what filter is filtering... It can be map/flatMap etc. It's all about accessing the object. As I said, my crash occurs when Realm object is deleted and I still have one in my Swift Array and try to access it.

Comment: As mentioned above, there's just not enough code to know what's going on. For example this function `let objects = databaseManager.getObjects()` is returning nil so the filter crashes. Maybe? Maybe not? Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, we don't know and won't be able to help.